# C# Is it possible to know username when invalid credentials occurs?

Tags: c#, wcf

In my service sometimes occurs this exception at error handler:

> system.servicemodel.security.securitynegotiationexception:
>   The server has rejected the client credentials. - The server has rejected the client credentials. - The logon attempt failed

Unfortunately, I can't get their parameters, but I do know what EventLog contains more brief explanation of what happened, including username.

Is it possible to retrieve this information inside error handler? I mean, security context is not initialized, and I can't get it, but therefore I need to notify user that something is off.
There is sample:

```cs
    //this is std WCF interface implementation.
    internal sealed class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            var securityException = error as SecurityNegotiationException;
            if (securityException != null)
            {
                var invalidCred = securityException.InnerException as InvalidCredentialException;
                if (invalidCred != null)
                {
                    //there it is, I need username here.
                    log.Warn(invalidCred, "Invalid credentials. See event log.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```